# PyTorch3D file io throws error - AttributeError: _evt

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch3d

I finally got PyTorch3D to install on my conda environment with the following configuration -- `torch=1.13.0` and `torchvision=0.14.0` and `pytorch3d=0.7.5`.

I am trying to load a mesh from an .obj file using pytorch3d.io from https://pytorch3d.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/modules/io.html.

In the line `pytorch3d.io.load_obj(filename)`, I get the below error

```
An exception occurred in telemetry logging.Disabling telemetry to prevent further exceptions.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aditya/miniconda3/envs/py3d/lib/python3.10/site-packages/iopath/common/file_io.py", line 946, in __log_tmetry_keys
    handler.log_event()
  File "/home/aditya/miniconda3/envs/py3d/lib/python3.10/site-packages/iopath/common/event_logger.py", line 97, in log_event
    del self._evt
AttributeError: _evt
```

I am on Nvidia RTX 4090 graphics card. Not sure what the issue is here.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this problem. I looked into the for iopath files and found the culprit:

```
def log_event(self, topic: Optional[str] = None):
    if b_tmetry_available and self._enabled:

        # Sample the current event.
        if not self._sample_record():
            return

        if topic is None:
            topic = self.DEFAULT_TOPIC

        for writer in self._writers:
            writer.writeRecord(topic, self._evt)
    del self._evt
    self._evt = SimpleEventRecord()
```

The last two lines should be under the conditional (they are not):

```
if b_tmetry_available and self._enabled:
```

When I did `conda intall` it gave me the version of iopath with this bug, but as of writing this the latest version on GitHub has this bug corrected.
https://github.com/facebookresearch/iopath/blob/main/iopath/common/event_logger.py

I noticed the import block as well:

```
try:
    from tmetry.simpleevent import SimpleEventRecord
    from tmetry.writer import TmetryWriter

    b_tmetry_available = True
except ImportError:
    b_tmetry_available = False
```

But `tmetry` is an internal tool used by the developers. So the fix, as per the latest version on GitHub, is that it should not execute those last two lines.

That said, I've done `conda update iopath` and it still gave me the broken version. I ended up fixing it manually for now.